# Is it possible to make a desktop shortcut of a Microsoft Remote Desktop host (not classic mstsc)?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, shortcuts

As a consecuence of the latest [Windows Updates](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2018-0886), we're migrating some classic mstsc connections to use Microsoft Remote Desktop application. We're doing this manually (adding host and credentials one by one).

This is not a serious problem, **but I wonder if a host shortcut can be made in a Windows 10 machine**. At the moment, you can pin it to Start menu. Moreover, shortcut of the Windows app can be added to Desktop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the "modern" app? I thought it got killed off a year ago, and MSTSC is still current.

Comment: Yes, didn't know anything about that.

Comment: I would definitely stick with .rdp files and use mstsc. This is the technology Microsoft uses for their remote app and remote desktop gateway services anyway.

Comment: The problem is that there's no official way to access gpedit.msc under certain Windows versions (Home edition). You need to change a directive in order to make it work (with the latest update).

Comment: I didn't know CredSSP is useful at all without Active Directory... Well, fortunately the settings go straight into the registry, as you can see at the bottom of the [MS support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093492/credssp-updates-for-cve-2018-0886-march-13-2018), so you can apply them via `.reg` files.

Comment: @grawity Thanks a lot man, I finally managed to do so by applying some registry keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Warning

Before using this registry hack, have a look at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093492/credssp-updates-for-cve-2018-0886-march-13-2018) Microsoft Support Article. It's **VERY** important that you know the risks, a better solution is to update the server you are trying to connect to.

Open your favorite text editor and **copy the following content**:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters]
"AllowEncryptionOracle"=dword:00000002
```

**Save it as fix.reg. Double click it, apply the registry changes and reboot your machine.**

You should be able to connect from now on.